# Variable position in comparision in PHP

Tags: php

Which is more optimized between 2 case below?

```
if ($var == 'value') {}
```

and

```
if ('value' == $var) {}
```

Sorry if this is duplicated with another question but I can not google out the answer.

Thanks

[UPDATE]

This's called Yoda Conditions, more information [here](http://wiert.me/2010/05/25/yoda-conditions-from-stackoverflow-new-programming-jargon-you-coined/).

Comment: If you want to optimize, use triple equals.

Comment: See [Yoda Conitions](http://wiert.me/2010/05/25/yoda-conditions-from-stackoverflow-new-programming-jargon-you-coined/). There is no difference in efficiency.

Comment: @Salketer It's called strict comparison.

Comment: @Fluffeh : thanks for giving me the story

Answer (score 7):

There's no actual difference. The second one is used to defend yourself from typo `if ($var = 'value')` But not really readable. Use mostly the first one unless you are so tired that while typing you miss characters.

If you write code

```
if ($var = 'val') echo $var; //Output will be "val"
```

but if you do

```
if ('val' = $var) echo $var;
```

You'll get syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

`'value' == $var` is called a yoda condition. And generally is not used, because it is less readable.

In performance matter, I'm not sure, but I guess your interpreter generate the exact same opcode.

Comment: The only difference kicks in when different data types get involved. Another interesting fact with this type of comparison is:

    false == array() evaluates to true
    false == "" evaluates to true
    array() == "" however, evaluates to false

See - http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: Really interesting rizwaniqbal.  More on programming jargon (like yoga condition) here : http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html

Comment: Very interesting :D Yoda condition, love the name, do I

Answer (score 1):

The mostly used one is `$var=="value"` and if you want to it optimize then instead of `==` use `===`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use

```
$var == 'value'
```

form to increase readability. I do not think there is a real performance gap between the two, php.net does not have any info on it (or i could not find it).