# Boolean evaluation in reverse

Tags: php, coding-style, boolean, evaluation, operator-precedence

Why is the boolean evaluation done in reverse in the following PHP code, as opposed to putting "false" at the end?

```
while (false !== ($obj = readdir($dh))) {
    // do something
}
```

(from one of the user examples in http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

I've seen this way of writing evaluations elsewhere but never really understood why it's done. I've never studied computer science so this might be a real 101 question.

Comment: Some companies have coding standards where the constants (false in this case) is put first. This is to try to avoid the error of having an erroneous assignment instead of a comparison.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable position in comparision in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560627/variable-position-in-comparision-in-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personal preference so you don't by mistake assign value instead of doing a comparison.

For example

```
// doesn't generate an error, hard to track
if($value = false)
...
```

but

```
// fatal error, you know that you did = instead of ==
if(false = $value)
```